Local Package Development with Poetry on Ubuntu 24.04?
I'm working on a Python project that uses Poetry for dependency management. Recently, I found a bug in a third-party package, so I cloned its repository to work on it locally. My goal is to integrate this local version of the package into my project, but I've run into some issues.
First, I attempted to manually add the package path to my pyproject.toml like this:
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
buggy-one = { path = './buggy-one' }

This does install the package, but not in editable mode, which is not ideal for development.
Next, I tried using pip install -e ./buggy-one to install the package in editable mode. Unfortunately, on newer versions of Ubuntu (like 24.04), this results in the following error:
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install python3-xyz...

The error message suggests using pipx as an alternative, but this isn't suitable for my needs since pipx installs the package in a separate environment, and I need to work on it within my Poetry-managed project.
Given these challenges, what is the correct approach in 2024 to work on a local package within a Poetry-managed project on Ubuntu? Is there a way to properly link the local package so that I can develop and test it simultaneously wi
New pip message on Ubuntu 24.04
Here the full new message you get if you try to use pip on Ubuntu 24.04:
$ pip install gettext 
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage 
    a virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx 
    installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or
OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of
breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing 
--break-system-packages.


Could not find a matching version of package buggy-one is probably caused by the fact that you have pinned down the package to a version that is not your local checkout. However never heard externally-managed-environment (error?) before. Is this something particular to this packge? pip just works.

@MikkoOhtamaa It is new to Ubuntu 24.04... You cannot use pip anymore :(

Why would you not? I am using pip on Ubuntu fine. Did you activate Poetry virtual environment using poetry shell command before running pip install?

@MikkoOhtamaa I've added the message I get when I use pip

that's because you need to activate the virtual environment before using pip, that's to prevent you from installing to the system-wide python

@juanpa.arrivillaga I am using poetry which is a virtual environment :(

@nowox poetry is not a virtual environment, but it creates ones for you automatically, which is what gets activated when you use poetry shell. So you can use poetry shell to activate the environment, or just activate it directly yourself, then use pip. Of course, I'm not sure this will all play nice since the whole point of poetry is to rely on it to manage your packages for your development environment and not pip...

@juanpa.arrivillaga it works, I use it every day.

Got it... With poetry shell + pip install -e it works : this is the anwer to my question

@nowox I'm not sure if it is the best approach though, but feel free to add it as an answer and you can wait and see if anyone else has a better approach using poetry

@MikkoOhtamaa yes, it should work if you activate the virtual environment

@nowox happy that you managed to resolve it out. Python package management can be a pain in the butt many times. Sorry that you had to go through this.

If you want to install a package under poetry, you must activate the environment on your current shell. This is possible with:
poetry shell

Then you can simply install whatever package you want.
